# Combobox trigger make disable/hidden from ext.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, wcf, ext.net

Which property is make combobox trigger disable/hidden or just read only? Thank you for your interested
My combobox is;

```
<ext:ComboBox runat="server" ID="cboStorageHouse" MinChars="0" LabelWidth="150" FieldLabel="Ambar"
                                                MaxHeight="22" DisplayField="Name" ValueField="ID" ForceSelection="False">
                                                <Listeners>
                                                </Listeners>
                                                <Store>
                                                    <ext:Store runat="server" ID="strStorageHouse" AutoDecode="True">
                                                        <Model>
                                                            <ext:Model runat="server" ID="mdlStorageHouseList" IDProperty="ID">
                                                                <Fields>
                                                                    <ext:ModelField Name="ID" Type="Int" />
                                                                    <ext:ModelField Name="Name" Type="String" />
                                                                </Fields>
                                                            </ext:Model>
                                                        </Model>
                                                    </ext:Store>
                                                </Store>
                                            </ext:ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi all i found solution maybe it will usefull for someone,

```
HideBaseTrigger="true"
```

This combobox properties solved my problem.